# Can I drain two clothes washers into a shared two-inch pipe?

Tags: code-compliance, p-trap

I am installing a second washing machine in a different part of the house and want to connect the two washers to the same drain(2 inch pipe). The current washer is in the basement with basic setup of vertical 2" pipe drain about 3 feet above concrete floor going down to trap about one foot from floor.

I want to install a second washer drain going through the main floor to the basement, across the basement ceiling about 20 feet, down basement wall about 8 feet to meet up with the first washer drain.  Both washers connecting through y-joint or t-joint would be emptying through the same p-trap.  Is that okay?

Comment: On the one hand, a washer is only 2 DFUs, so 2 is only 4 and that's no problem for a 2 inch drain. On the other, I contemplate the situation where both are pumping out at the same time and have my doubts.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing , 2 dumping at the same time may be an issue.+

Answer (score 1):

See the attached diagram.  It doesn't sound that you can meet these requirements.

[image: laundry drain]

Comment: To be more specific, you'd be too far from the vent line and too far above the trap weir. You'd need a separate trap at the new washer location and a nearby vent.